# Splicing text file when marker is reached

Tags: python

I have a master file which is a collection of newspaper articles and I need to put each newspaper article into its own file. Thankfully, the last line of each article is the copyright notice, so I wrote the following to try to accomplish what I want automatically:

```
def splicearticles():
    countart = 1
    new_file = "article1.txt"
    with open("newspaperarticles.txt", "r") as my_file:
        with open("temporaryarticle.txt", "a+") as my_temporary:
            for line in my_file:
                if line.strip() != "Reserved by Author":
                    currentline = line.strip() + "\n"
                    my_temporary.write(currentline)
                else:
                    with open(new_file, "w") as my_final:
                        my_final.write(my_temporary.read())
                    countart += 1
                    new_file = "article" + str(countart) + ".txt"
                    my_temporary.truncate(0)
```

The problem seems to lie with `my_final.write(my_temporary.read())` since all the other parts of the code are executed. Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need to `seek` to the beginning of the temporary file before reading from it.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to accomplish with the temporary file: I wouldn't use a temporary file at all, you can read lines into a local variable and then append (or write) all of them to the final file.

Comment: That seems to have done it:) Thanks! 

G B, this is pretty rough code, and you're definitely right about using a local variable. I'll tinker with it a bit to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                with open(new_file, "w") as my_final:
                    my_final.write(my_temporary.read())
```

When you execute `my_temporary.read()` here, the file position is pointed at the end of your temporary file. So the `read` call won't read anything. Try returning the file position to the beginning of the file first.

```
                with open(new_file, "w") as my_final:
                    my_temporary.seek(0)
                    my_final.write(my_temporary.read())
```

---

Alternatively, just don't use a temporary file object at all. You could just as easily store your lines in a list.

```
def splicearticles():
    countart = 1
    new_file = "article1.txt"
    with open("newspaperarticles.txt", "r") as my_file:
        temp = []
        for line in my_file:
            if line.strip() != "Reserved by Author":
                currentline = line.strip() + "\n"
                temp.append(currentline)
            else:
                with open(new_file, "w") as my_final:
                    my_final.write("".join(temp))
                countart += 1
                new_file = "article" + str(countart) + ".txt"
                temp = []
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easier if you use a regex.

Suppose you have the file representing 3 articles like this:

```
Article 1
Blah blah blah blah did blah

Reserved by Author

Article 2
This article goes on and on
end of that article
Reserved by Author

Now we have article 3
blah blah
And it goes on
```

You can memory map the file to make it look like a string without loading it all in memory. This allows you to use a regex on the file contents and splitting on the delimiter of 'Reserved by Author':

```
import re
import mmap

fn='/tmp/articles.txt'

with open(fn) as articles:
    mf=mmap.mmap(articles.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    chunks=re.finditer(r'(.+?)(?:Reserved by Author\s*\n|\Z)', mf, re.S | re.M)
    for i, block in enumerate(chunks, 1):
        text=block.group(1)
        with open('/tmp/article {}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(text)
```

With this trivial example, we create 3 new files:

```
$ cat "article 1.txt"
Article 1
Blah blah blah blah did blah

$ cat "article 2.txt"
Article 2
This article goes on and on
end of that article

$ cat "article 3.txt"
Now we have article 3
blah blah
And it goes on
```